# Count Instances of Class

Tags: java, .net, testing

I am looking for a way to programatically get the number of instances of a certain class type in .NET and Java.

Say for example I have class Foo.  I want to be able to, in the same process, get a current count of all instance of Foo.
However I cannot modify Foo, so a static int with counting is out.  Also I cannot just add all instances I make to some static list and count that.  I want to be able to just say:

```
System.GC.numberOf< Foo >()
```

or something.

I was looking through the garbage collectors but I could not find any relevant methods.

Comment: there are duplicates to this. search around.

Comment: there are similar questions but the answers always involve modifying the class with some sort of counter.  I want to count instances of classes I do not define or control

Comment: well, you can't. that is also stated in some answers.

Comment: The keep track of the number of objects you create in code you do control.

Comment: I have used tools to count instances of objects in remote processes, very useful for tracking down leaks.  I am hoping there is a way to replicate this logic in the same program for testing purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another somewhat exotic way to do it would be to use aspect-oriented techniques to instrument the constructor(s) of the class(es) in question. Take a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/index.php), for example.

Comment: Going to shoot for this solution since I can probably instrument .net classes too in some other similar way.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't modify the class directly (perhaps because it is a built-in class?), could you create a wrapper, or a subclass that inherits the original?

```
public class subFoo extends foo
{
    protected static int count = 0;

    public subFoo() 
    {
        count++;
        super();
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    {
        count--;
        super.finalize();
    } 

    public static int getInstanceCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

This example is Java and may have some syntax issues 'cause I'm a little rusty.

Of course, you'd have to be sure to redeclare all your `foo` as `subFoo` throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: This did cross my mind, but unfortunately what I am dealing with are objects generated by a third party library.  I want to count these objects while running automated tests to make sure they are being properly released. +1 for reading the question and offering a good solution though!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control of how the Java VM is being run? If so, you can write a quick and dirty debugger agent...  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#writingAgents

See the events "VM Object Allocation" and "Object Free"

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, there are similar questions in SO.
One hack you can use - a big one IMO - is to *change* the `Object` class: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262620/how-to-find-the-number-of-objects-in-the-heap/2262965#2262965)

Resume:

- copy the source of Object
- add counting to its constructor (finalize)
- add method to read the count
- prepend the directory with the compiled class to the boot classpath (-Xbootclasspath)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: if you can't change the class, maybe you can just put a counter in another part of the project, incrementing it when you instantiate said class?