# No. of Objects created in Java

Tags: java

How many objects are created in the 4 situations mentioned below?

```
int[] array = new int[10];

String[]  str = new String[10];

Edit 1 : 

String[] str = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

Edit 2 : 


String[] str1 = new String[10]; 

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
         str1[i] = "Str";
    }
```

Comment: only 2 array object will create for this.

Comment: Every time you use "new", you create 1 new object. That's it. As long as you don't fill these arrays, you have just allocated space.

Comment: Miche is correct, although the use of 'new' can be hidden.. either within another objects constructor, or the short hand array syntax

Comment: @Miche : And if those get filled with 10strings, does not then it makes 11 objects in case of a array of type String

Comment: If you fill your array with primitive types such as Int, then there will only be one object (the array), but if you fill them with Objects such as Strings, then indeed you will have those 10 objects + the array. However, that is just the conceptual level and does not mean much in terms of memory management.

Comment: @Miche : Chris K believes something else. All the answers so far i have received differ in one or other way round. I think no one is pretty sure. Is there any way to calculate the number of objects created in the above program? This one does not work for arrays?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262620/how-to-find-the-number-of-objects-in-the-heap

Comment: I think although we're more or less on the same page, Chris K's answer is much more accurate and complete than mine, you should use it as a good basis for understanding how this works.

Comment: @Miche : How come you are on the same page with Chris when for String str = new String[10], Chris says 1 object gets created (even after initialisation) and you said 11 objects.

Comment: No you didn't understand, I said it will create 11 objects IF YOU FILL IT. When you do new String[10], you just allocate the space, but there is nothing in your array, so that is just 1 object.

Comment: That's why i mention (even after initialisation) in above comment, Chris is saying 1 object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java arrays are a single object.  And allocating a new array can only ever allocate that one object.  Allocations can be nested, either by writing new within the array initialisation block, auto boxing or by an objects constructor also calling new in a form of chained action.

**The answers to your three cases are:  1, 1 and 1.  Details below, along with some other examples to highlight special cases.**

Strings and autoboxed ints can also be special cases, as the JVM has special caches for those.  Details in the following commented examples:

```
// 1 object, an array with 10 elements (set to zero)
int[] array = new int[10]; 

// 1 objects, an array with 10 elements (set to null)
String[]  str = new String[10];  

// 1 object, an array with 10 elements pointing at objects 
// that have been preallocated within the String pool.  See 
// the appendium below for evidence.
String[] str = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" }; 

// 3 objects, one for the array and one per integer.
Integer[] a4 = new Integer[] { new Integer(1), new Integer(2) }; 

// 1 object again, Java has an Integer pool of limited size which is used
// to optimise auto boxing; 1 and 2 will definitely be within that default
// range
Integer[] a6 = new Integer[] { 1, 2 }; 

// 3 objects, the default size of the int pool is fairly low
// but it can be increased via a JVM flag.
Integer[] a5 = new Integer[] { 1000, 2000 }; 

// 3-5 objects -- 1 for the array, one for each of the string objects and 1 
// per char array backing the string.  Depending on JVM version the char 
// array may be shared with the interned strings, so that one is a little tricky
// and is why I said 3-5.
String[] str = {new String("1"), new String("2")};
```

**Appendium**

Just for fun, here is evidence of the constant pool in action.

The following Java code compiles down to the following byte codes, notice that only the array gets allocated.  The elements are using class pool constants.  I have cut the output short, it just repeats the same code for each element (dup, iconst,ldc,aastore,...)

java code:

```
String[] str = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
```

JVM byte code:

```
   0: bipush        10
   2: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
   5: dup           
   6: iconst_0      
   7: ldc           #3                  // load constant from class pool - String 1
   9: aastore                           // store into array
  10: dup           
  11: iconst_1      
  12: ldc           #4                  // String 2
  14: aastore       
  15: dup           
  16: iconst_2
```

Answer (score 2):

2 `Array` objects are created.

```
int[] array = new int[10];// can hold 10 ints

String[]  str = new String[10]; // can hold references to 10 Strings
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your first two statements create 1 object each (an array).

The third is a bit special. You create a String-array (1 object) filled with references to 10 Strings (10 objects). So, that's 11 objects.

Not quite though. String literals in Java are pooled, meaning basically that there's a special place in memory where all String literals are kept. So, if you use the String `"string"` in two different places in your code, you're both referring to the same object. You can't really say new objects are being created if you use String literals.

Even if you did say so (because they don't 'exist' in the pool if they are used nowhere in your code) this means that whether or not the third line 'creates' new objects basically depends on how many of those string are also used elsewhere in your program.