# How to check the number of objects created in heap memory?

Tags: java, memory

I want to see how many objects are created by Java when I run my program.

My intention is if I use the code `String s = new String("Hi");` I want to see how many objects Java will create. Later I want to try with `String news = "Hi";`

This is my sample program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String("Hi");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I am using `Scanner` just to avoid the program to terminate.

I have gone through this SO post [How to find the number of objects in the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262620/how-to-find-the-number-of-objects-in-the-heap) and tried to use `jvisualvm`, but the tool is not giving the count of my objects created in my class. I also do not understand how to get the actual count of objects based on below image.

[image]

When I tried to use the command `jmap -heap <pid>` then I get below error:

> Attaching to process ID 15101, please wait... Error attaching to
>   process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to
>   the process

If I use eclipse Debug as option, then I see that it is not the correct way to find out the number of objects that are being created.

Comment: Well actually it does - instances column

Comment: You are creating so little objects that it hardly matters.  If you want to know exactly how many objects there are I suggest you use your debugger.  If you have millions or billions of objects, using a profiler is more useful.  BTW VisualVM creates thousadns of objects per second when it runs so anything less than this is likely to get lost in the noise.

Comment: @Antoniossss, The instances column is changing very frequently. Also it says 20K instances created for String. So how will I know how many objects were created for my single line of code `new String()`? Can you please tell me

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Thanks, now it is clear why I see so many objects in JvisualVM. When you say debugger, are you telling that I have to say "Debug as Java Application in eclipse"? Can you please give some more details, because I have tried the eclipse debug, that is not a correct answer.

Comment: @user3181365 When you step into code in a debugger you can see each object as it is created. Some methods it won't show you but you will be able to see all the objects if you place them in variables. Since you have at most 3 objects with `String s = new String("hi");`, you can easily count them.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I am using eclipse, now in my code if I write `String s1 = "Hi"` 3 times, then as per Java only single object should be created, but in eclipse I am seeing 3 instances being created. Are you referring to any other debugger?

Comment: `"Hi"` creates two objects the first time, a `String` and a `char[]`. After that you will keep getting the same object.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, can you please tell me what debugger you are referring to? Sorry my earlier comment said 2 instead of 3, I have corrected it.

Comment: I use IntelliJ but all debuggers should show you the same information.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Thanks a lot peter for giving answers, but I am not able to find the correct answer using my eclipse debug option. I am looking for a tool which helps to show all the objects created by our application.

Comment: @user3181365 you can use jmap to extract all the objects in an application, but it's only useful for trivial programs. When you have millions or billions of objects, the last thing you want is to be looking at them all. If it takes you one second to look at an object, it will take you 12 days without a break to look at one million objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your debugger you can see that

[image]

The `String@437` object is the same in `s1` `s2` `s3` but this refers to a `char[2]@438` which is another object. Thus you have two objects.

Comment: I agree that s1, s2, and s3 reference the same object, but I don't believe that's evident from the debugger, because the hash code is based on the contents, not the memory location. If the code had `s4 = new String("hi")`, that would have the same hash code but a different memory location.

Answer (score -1):

In 2017 edition of Intellij idea there is a window named "[Memory view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-objects-in-the-jvm-heap.html)" in debugger page.

The functionality is provided by a JVMTI (Tool Interface) agent at https://github.com/JetBrains/debugger-memory-agent.