# How many array objects will be created in java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to understand the number of objects created with the below snippet:

```
int[][] a= new int[4][3];  //with this line first.
```

And, secondly if I re-initialize `a` with:

```
a = new int[3][7]; //finally with this line also.
```

Also, let me know if there is any tool to check the number of objects created in my complete application.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: [you can use jmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262620/how-to-find-the-number-of-objects-in-the-heap) or some other ide tools

Comment: @Henry yup, skipped that 2d array, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Number of arrays in multiple dimensions will be 1 for the array + 1 * size of first sub array size + 1 * size of first sub array size * size of second sub array size and so on... exclude the last dimension which contain the integer values

etc:

```
a = int[4][3] // 1 + 1 * 4 = 5 arrays
b = int[3][7] // 1 + 1 * 3 = 4 arrays
c = int[5][6][7] // 1 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 5 * 6 = 36 arrays
```

Comment: So there will be 1 object for each array in multi dimensional array. Hence a = new int[4][3] will give 5 objects, right?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of 1 object for each array. In a = new  int[4][3], your pointer a is array of arrays, size 4. Each one of them is array of int[3]. So it will be 5 as you wrote

Comment: As in the question I was asking about the number of array objects created, hence I used the term 'object'.